# What is wrong with my Max function? The error message i get is cannot get aggregate function in groupby clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT 
    skm_vrecommendations.cno, Max (skm_vrecommendations.decno)
FROM 
    skm_vrecommendations 
INNER JOIN 
    skm_voutcome ON (skm_vrecommendations.cno = skm_voutcome.cno) 
                 AND (skm_vrecommendations.refdt = skm_voutcome.refdt) 
                 AND (skm_vrecommendations.decno = skm_voutcome.decno)
WHERE 
    (((skm_vrecommendations.reccode) = 39) 
    AND ((skm_voutcome.visitdt) BETWEEN #1/1/2018# AND #1/31/2018#))
GROUP BY
    skm_vrecommendations.cno, MAX(skm_vrecommendations.decno)
```

What is wrong with my `MAX` function?

The error message I get is

> Cannot use aggregate function in group by clause

Answer (score 0):

you can not group by MAX. I think you just want this, remove the MAX in the gropu by clause.  This will give you the max skm_vrecommendations.decno for every skm_vrecommendations.cno.

```
SELECT skm_vrecommendations.cno, Max (skm_vrecommendations.decno) 
FROM skm_vrecommendations 
INNER JOIN skm_voutcome ON (skm_vrecommendations.cno = skm_voutcome.cno) 
AND (skm_vrecommendations.refdt = skm_voutcome.refdt) 
AND (skm_vrecommendations.decno = skm_voutcome.decno) 
WHERE (((skm_vrecommendations.reccode)=39) 
AND ((skm_voutcome.visitdt) Between #1/1/2018# And #1/31/2018#)) 
group by skm_vrecommendations.cno
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use max in group by

```
SELECT skm_vrecommendations.cno
    , Max (skm_vrecommendations.decno)
FROM skm_vrecommendations 
INNER JOIN skm_voutcome ON (skm_vrecommendations.cno = skm_voutcome.cno) 
    AND (skm_vrecommendations.refdt = skm_voutcome.refdt) 
    AND (skm_vrecommendations.decno = skm_voutcome.decno)
WHERE (((skm_vrecommendations.reccode)=39) 
    AND ((skm_voutcome.visitdt) Between #1/1/2018# And #1/31/2018#))
group by skm_vrecommendations.cno
```

in group by you must add  only the columns not involved in aggregation function (in this case only skm_vrecommendations.cno)

Answer (score 0):

This part needs to be removed.

group by skm_vrecommendations.cno`, Max (skm_vrecommendations.decno)`

Answer (score 0):

SELECT skm_vrecommendations.cno, Max(skm_vrecommendations.decno) AS MaxOfdecno
FROM skm_vrecommendations INNER JOIN skm_voutcome ON (skm_vrecommendations.decno = skm_voutcome.decno) AND (skm_vrecommendations.refdt = skm_voutcome.refdt) AND (skm_vrecommendations.cno = skm_voutcome.cno)
WHERE (((skm_vrecommendations.reccode)=39) AND ((skm_voutcome.visitdt) Between #1/1/2018# And #1/31/2018#))
GROUP BY skm_vrecommendations.cno, (skm_vrecommendations.decno);

All that had to be done was "Remove the Max from Group by"
Thanks